# I want to display data from mongoDB to treeview in Python tkinter

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter

I saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0l0r0PekvM&t=20s
The code could display data but it display by many Grid together so i can not create a Scrollbar.

you can see the function display data in CRUD() -> creategrid(n)

sorry for my bad English ^^

my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pymongo
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pybase64 as base64
import gridfs



myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["enrollmentsystem"] #database file
mycol = mydb["employees"]
mycol2 = mydb["fs.files"]



def CRUD():
    lst=[["ID","Name","Age","Departure","Gender","Skill","Working (Y)","Trained (Y)","Salary"]]
    window=tk.Toplevel(w1)

    window.title("UPDATE PROFILE")
    window.geometry('300x400')
    window.configure(bg="bisque2")
    
    window3=tk.Toplevel(window)
    window3.title("UPDATE PROFILE")
    window3.geometry('+%d+%d' % (100,100))
    window3.configure(bg="bisque2")
 
    def callback(event):
        global lstindex
        li=[]
        li=event.widget._values
        lstindex=li[1]
        cid.set(lst[li[1]][0])
        cname.set(lst[li[1]][1])
        cage.set(lst[li[1]][2])
        cdept.set(lst[li[1]][3])
        cgender.set(lst[li[1]][4])
        cskill.set(lst[li[1]][5])  
        cwyear.set(lst[li[1]][6])
        ctyear.set(lst[li[1]][7])
        csalary.set(lst[li[1]][8])
   
    def creategrid(n):


        lst.clear()
        lst.append(["ID","Name","Age","Departure","Gender","Skill","Working (Y)","Trained (Y)","Salary"])
        cursor = mycol.find({})
        
        for text_fromDB in cursor:
            empid=str(text_fromDB["empid"])
            empname=str(text_fromDB["empname"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empage=str(text_fromDB["empage"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empdept=str(text_fromDB["empdept"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empgender=str(text_fromDB["empgender"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empskill=str(text_fromDB["empskill"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empwyear=int(text_fromDB["empwyear"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            emptyear=int(text_fromDB["emptyear"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            empsalary=float(text_fromDB["empsalary"].encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
            lst.append([empid,empname,empage,empdept,empgender,empskill,empwyear,emptyear,empsalary])
            
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for j in range(len(lst[0])):
                mgrid=tk.Entry(window3,width=10)
                mgrid.insert(tk.END, lst[i][j])
                mgrid._values =mgrid.get(),i
                mgrid.grid(row=i+12,column=j+11)
                mgrid.bind("<Button-1>",callback)


        if n==1:
            for label in window.grid_slaves():
                if int(label.grid_info()["row"]) >11:
                    label.grid_forget()
                     
    def msgbox(msg,titlebar):
        result = messagebox.askokcancel(title=titlebar, message=msg)
        return result


    def save():

        r=msgbox("save record?","record")
        if r==True:
            newid = mycol.count_documents({})
            if newid!=0:
                newid = mycol.find_one(sort=[("empid", -1)])["empid"]
            id=newid+1
            cid.set(id)

            mydict = {"empid": int(custid.get()),"empname":custname.get(), "empage":custage.get(),
                      "empdept":custdept.get(),"empgender":custgender.get(),"empskill":custskill.get(),
                      "empwyear":custwyear.get(),"emptyear":custtyear.get(),"empsalary":custsalary.get()}
            x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
            messagebox.showinfo("info", "save completed, please add photo")

            
            creategrid(1)
            creategrid(0)
    def delete():
        r=msgbox("Delete?", "record")
        if r ==True:
            myquery = {"empid":int(custid.get())}
            mycol.delete_one(myquery)
            creategrid(1)
            creategrid(0)

    def update():
        r=msgbox("Update?","record")
        if r ==True:
            myquery={"empid":int(custid.get())}
            newvalues={"$set":{"empname":custname.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)

            newvalues={"$set":{"empage":custage.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)

            newvalues={"$set":{"empdept":custdept.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)
            
            newvalues={"$set":{"empgender":custgender.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)
            
            newvalues={"$set":{"empskill":custskill.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)
            
            newvalues={"$set":{"empwyear":custwyear.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)
            
            newvalues={"$set":{"emptyear":custtyear.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)

            newvalues={"$set":{"empsalary":custsalary.get()}}
            mycol.update_one(myquery,newvalues)
            
            creategrid(1)
            creategrid(0)
    def upload_file(): # Image upload and display
        global filename,img, fs
        f_types =[('Png files','*.png'),('Gif Files', '*.gif'),('PMG files','*.pmg'),('jpg files','*.jpg')]
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types,defaultextension='.png')
        img=Image.open(filename)
        img=img.resize((150,150)) # new width & height
        img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        e1 =tk.Label(picker)
        e1.grid(row=15,column=1)
        e1.image = img
        e1['image']=img

    def saveimage():
        global filename
        r=msgbox("save image?","image")
        if r==True:

                # encode image to binary text
                with open(filename, "rb") as image:
        # read the image as text and convert it to binary
                      image_string = base64.b64encode(image.read())

    # create Gridfs instance
                fs = gridfs.GridFS(mydb)
    # add the image to database
        def alreadyExists():
            return bool(mycol2.find_one({'filename' : custid.get()}))
        if alreadyExists() == True:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "ID exist")
        else:
            
        
    
            put_image = fs.put(image_string, filename = custid.get())

    picker = tk.Frame(window,width=150, height=150)
    picker.place(x=1, y=250)
    
    
    b2 = tk.Button(window, text='Upload photo', 
    command = lambda:upload_file()).place(x=180, y=310)


    b3 = tk.Button(window, text='Save photo', 
    command = lambda:saveimage()).place(x=180, y=340)

            
    label =tk.Label(window, text="EMPLOYEE ENLISTMENT FORM", width=25, height=1, bg="cornflower blue",anchor="center")
    label.grid(column=2, row=1)

    label = tk.Label(window, text="Employee ID:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=2)
    cid = tk.StringVar() 
    custid = tk.Entry(window,width=33, textvariable=cid)
    custid.grid(column=2, row=2)
    custid.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    label = tk.Label(window, text="Employee Name:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=3)
    cname = tk.StringVar() 
    custname = tk.Entry(window,width=33, textvariable=cname)
    custname.grid(column=2, row=3)


    age = []
    for i in range(1960,2002):
        age.append(i)
    label=tk.Label(window, text="Employee BirthYear:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(row=4,column=1)
    cage = tk.IntVar()
    custage = ttk.Combobox(window,width=30, values=age)
    custage.grid(row=4,column=2)


    label=tk.Label(window, text="Employee Departure:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(row=5,column=1)
    cdept = tk.StringVar() 
    dept=['Sale','Marketing']
    custdept = ttk.Combobox(window,width=30, values=dept)
    custdept.grid(row=5,column=2)



    label=tk.Label(window, text="Employee Gender:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(row=6,column=1)
    gender=['Male','Female']
    cgender = tk.StringVar() 
    custgender = ttk.Combobox(window,width=30, values=gender)
    custgender.grid(row=6,column=2)



    label=tk.Label(window, text="Employee Skill:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(row=7,column=1)
    cskill = tk.StringVar()
    skill=['SQL, C#, Python','SQL, C#, C++','SQL, Python, C++','SQL, C++','SQL, Python','SQL, C#']
    custskill = ttk.Combobox(window,width=30, values=skill)
    custskill.grid(row=7,column=2)


    label = tk.Label(window, text="Employee WorkingYear:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=8)
    cwyear = tk.IntVar() 
    custwyear = tk.Entry(window,width=33, textvariable=cwyear)
    custwyear.grid(column=2, row=8)


    label = tk.Label(window, text="Employee Trained (Y):", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=9)
    ctyear = tk.IntVar() 
    custtyear = tk.Entry(window,width=33, textvariable=ctyear)
    custtyear.grid(column=2, row=9)


    label = tk.Label(window, text="Employee Salary:", width=20, height=1, bg="cadet blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=10)
    csalary = tk.DoubleVar() 
    custsalary = tk.Entry(window,width=33, textvariable=csalary)
    custsalary.grid(column=2, row=10)




    creategrid(1) #create textfield grid vi o tren chay tu grid 1


    savebtn = tk.Button(window,text="Save", command=save).place(x=180, y=275)
    savebtn = tk.Button(window,text="Delete", command=delete).place(x=220, y=275)
    savebtn = tk.Button(window,text="Update", command=update).place(x=270, y=275)
        
        

    btnClose=tk.Button(window, text="Close me", command=window.destroy).place(x=180, y=370)

# Tim kiem anh dua tren ID

def searchImage():
    window2=tk.Toplevel(w1)
    window2.title("BROWSE")
    window2.geometry('+%d+%d' % (100,100))

    picker2 = tk.Frame(window2,width=30, height=1)
    picker2.grid(row=1, column=3,rowspan = 10)
    a = tk.Entry(picker2,width=33)
    a.grid(column=2, row=11)
    def checkid():
        def alreadyExists():
            return bool(mycol2.find_one({'filename' : a.get()}))


        if alreadyExists() == True:
                        messagebox.showinfo("info", "ID exist")
                        fs = gridfs.GridFS(mydb)
                        data = mycol2.find_one({'filename' : a.get()})
                        my_id = data['_id']
                        outputdata =fs.get(my_id).read()
                        outputdata=outputdata.decode()
                        outputdata = base64.b64decode((outputdata))      
                        dowloadlocation = "image.jpg"
                        output = open(dowloadlocation, "wb")
                        output.write(outputdata)
                        output.close()
                        
                        bgetdisplay.config(state='active')
                        


        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "ID doesn't exist, please retype")
            bgetdisplay.config(state='disabled')

    def display():
        root = Toplevel(window2)
        path = "image.jpg"
        img = Image.open(path)
        img=img.resize((300,300))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
        panel.photo = img
        panel.grid(column=1,row=1)

    bgetdisplay = tk.Button(window2,state ='disabled', text='display image',
                            width=10,height=2,command = lambda:display())
    bgetdisplay.grid(column = 5, row = 2)

        

    bgetid = tk.Button(window2, text='checkID', 
        width=10,height=2,command = lambda:checkid()).grid(column = 4 ,row = 2)



    
    label = tk.Label(picker2, text="browse photo(input id):", width=20, height=1, bg="cornflower blue")
    label.grid(column=1, row=11)




    
w1=Tk()

    
btnOpen=tk.Button(w1,text ="Create, update, Delete",width=20,height=4, command=CRUD).place(x=120, y=20)
btnOpen=tk.Button(w1,text ="Search photo",width=20,height=4, command=searchImage).place(x=120, y=100)



w1.geometry('400x200')
w1.title("HUMAN RESOURES")



w1.mainloop()
```

I want to display data in a treeview to create a scrollbar.
Can anyone help to to change this display code

Comment: What’s stopping you from doing it? The tree view widget is documented, and there are many examples on the internet.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Bryan, my main problem is "add a scrollbar to the window had some Grids. I have tried to search the solution on the internet and i find the pack() method. But Pack() and Grid() cant exist together. So I try to create Treeview but i dont know "How to display datas in MongoDB  to the Treeview" ( i tried to search this).

Comment: You're not going to find a specific answer to a specific question, but there's plenty of documentation and examples for creating a treeview, and for getting data out of a db, so you just need to follow the documentation to read the data and the insert it in a treeview.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `pack` and `grid` in the same application as long as you don't use both of them for widgets that have the same parent.

Comment: Thank for your help, I will try  again. I'm new in tkinter so i can't understand some concept clearly yet.